Decrypting ed25519/cv25519 gpg keys in a python program
I am trying to decrypt a GPG encrypted file that uses the ed25519 algorithm. After enabling debugging in the Python module, I discovered that the gnupg Python module does not yet support the ed25519/cv25519 algorithm.
__version__ = '0.5.2'
__author__ = 'Vinay Sajip'
__date__ = '$12-Dec-2023 07:52:07$'

Here is the output after enabling debugging:
DEBUG:gnupg:gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available
DEBUG:gnupg:[GNUPG:] END_DECRYPTION
DEBUG:gnupg:stdout reader: <Thread(Thread-14, initial daemon)>
WARNING:gnupg:gpg returned a non-zero error code: 2
DEBUG:gnupg:decrypt result[:100]: b''
Decryption Status:  decryption failed
Decryption Stderr:  [GNUPG:] ENC_TO 6E9FF466ADE3A57D 18 0
gpg: encrypted with 0-bit [?] key, ID ADFAA57C, created 2022-01-20
      "MYID <myid@email.com>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: unknown pubkey algorithm
[GNUPG:] ERROR pkdecrypt_failed 4
[GNUPG:] BEGIN_DECRYPTION
[GNUPG:] DECRYPTION_FAILED
gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available
[GNUPG:] END_DECRYPTION

However I am able to execute the following command on a shell for decrypting the file indicating that underlying gpg binary supports the algorithm:
echo my_secret_pass_phrase | gpg --decrypt -o ./mydecryptedfile.txt ./myencryptedfile.gpg 

How do I execute this command from within python? I tried the following subprocess call command:
cmd = ['echo', pass_phrase, '|', 'gpg', '--decrypt', '-o', './mydecryptedfile.txt', 
       './myencryptedfile.gpg' ]
resp= subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
print(resp)

resp code above prints 0 but I don't see the decrypted file.

I have written a blog post related to this experience: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/my-gnupg-adventure-streamlining-aws-lambda-2024-yagna-pant-zk5dc/

I finally figured out the problem after going through several debugging steps and workarounds.
My use case was to have the GPG program available on an AWS Lambda function in Python such that when an encrypted file is uploaded to an S3 bucket, the Lambda function could decrypt the file. Since the GPG program was not available in the AWS default Lambda runtime environment, I followed the advice given in this Stack Overflow link: How to use GnuPG in an AWS Lambda function to build the static GPG executable and upload it along with my Lambda functions and the GnuPG Python wrapper.
As suggested, I built the static executable based on GnuPG-1.4.23 (dated: 2018-06-11) on a Rocky Linux 9 machine.
The problem of inconsistent results was due to using two different versions of the library. GnuPG-1.4.23 doesn't support the latest algorithms. My GPG file was encrypted using ed25519, and the static GPG binary I built on the Rocky Linux 9 platform didn't support this newer algorithm. By default, Rocky Linux 9 also had a newer version of the program. So, when the parameter in the GnuPG Python library was set to ("./gpg"), it used the static library I built for decryption. However, when I executed the program on a terminal, it used the default GPG binary installed at /usr/bin/gpg, hence the different behavior.
The way GPG works changed significantly from GnuPG-1.4.23 to later versions starting at 2.x.x, where the later versions require gpg-agent. Compiling the latest version of GPG 2.4.5 statically on Rocky Linux didn't solve the problem because it also required gpg-agent, and I couldn't find straightforward instructions on how to build it. Moreover, there were references indicating that there was no option to specify the location of the gpg-agent, and it always looked for the agent being available in the default location /usr/bin/gpg-agent. Since it had to run on an AWS Lambda, I needed to specify the location of the gpg-agent and couldn't figure out a way to install the gpg-agent in the /usr/bin directory.
To resolve this, I ended up building a Docker image with all the required packages and libraries. This way, I could bundle the necessary GPG binary and gpg-agent within the Docker container, ensuring that all dependencies were correctly configured and available at runtime. I initially tried creating an EC2 instance based on Amazon Linux 2023, thinking it would make it easier for running Lambda as it's their product. However, I found only the GPG binary was available but not the gpg-agent, which seemed very strange. So, I ended up building a Docker image based on the example provided by AWS on a Debian platform. Here is my full Dockerfile:
# Define custom function directory, for copy all files to docker
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/function"

FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/python:bookworm as build-image
# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR

# Copy function code
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY app/* ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install aws-lambda-cpp build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
  g++ \
  make \
  cmake \
  unzip \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev

# Install the function's dependencies
RUN pip install \
  --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} \
  awslambdaric

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} \
  -r ${FUNCTION_DIR}/requirements.txt

FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/python:bookworm

RUN apt-get install -y \
  gnupg \
  gnupg-agent \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy GnuPG default's configuration file
COPY gpg.conf /etc/gnupg/gpgconf.conf
RUN mkdir -p /root/.gnupg \
&& chmod 700 /root/.gnupg
COPY gpg.conf /root/.gnupg/
RUN chmod 600 /root/.gnupg/gpg.conf

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
# Set working directory to function root directory
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}
VOLUME "/root/.gnupg/"
RUN chsh -s /bin/bash

# Copy in the built dependencies
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# CMD ["/bin/bash","--login","-i"] # needed for docker interactive session

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/python", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]
CMD [ "app.lambda_handler"]


Here is the content of requirements.txt:
#gnupg # already had gnupg.py uploaded to my app folder
boto3   # needed for python lambda to make AWS API calls.

And here is the content of gpg.conf:
# see https://riseup.net/en/security/message-security/openpgp/best-practices
keyserver hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
keyserver-options no-honor-keyserver-url

personal-cipher-preferences AES256 AES192 AES CAST5
personal-digest-preferences SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224
cert-digest-algo SHA512
default-preference-list SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224 AES256 AES192 AES CAST5 ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP Uncompressed

With the above configuration, I was able to install version 2.2.12 of GPG and successfully decrypt the ed25519 encrypted files. This resolved the issues with the unsupported algorithms in the earlier versions of GPG.
Additionally, here is a note on how to enter the passphrase from within a Python program using a system command:
pass_phrase = read-from-secrets-manager(pass_phrase_name)

os.system('gpg --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase "%s" --decrypt -o dest-file.xml ./src-file.gpg' % pass_phrase)

